# referencing jquery global variables inside html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery.

I have below line of code: i just need to refer the variable inside html () function.

```
$('#myform #formProgress').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Saving&hellip;');
```

Now img src i have in a variable as below.

```
var url = document.location.host;
var url2 = url.concat("/MyApp/public/images/ajax-loader.gif");
```

Now inside i need to pass `url2` as `img src` tag.  how can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: ok thats quite easy, just set a id for the img element like this `<img src="..." id="image" />` then make a call from jquery to change it like this, `$('#image').attr('src',url2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

```
$(...).html('<img src="' + url2 + '"/>Saving...')
```

Or:

```
$(...).append($('<img/>').attr('src', url2))
```

The second method is cleaner/better IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation (the `+` operator with strings).  This has nothing to do with jQuery specifically and is a very simple JavaScript (and general string handling) concept.

```
.html('<img src="' + url2 + '"> Saving&helliop;');
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the question (as asked) is a basic javascript issue, not jQuery. jQuery is not a new language, people.